# Compute the limit of the integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Compute

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{n} (1 + \frac{x}{2n})^ne^{-x}dx$$

Edit: We have now learned the dominated convergence theorem. I think it is now a good idea to attempt the question that way. There is already an answer here, so I can't really delete the question. I thought I'd edit it and see if anyone wants to jump in!

Comment: Hint: The left factor converges to the exponential function.

Comment: @jojobo but I still need a way to bring the limit inside to do that. Can I do that with BND or monotone convergence?

Comment: Hint : Dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @CHAMSI as I said, I have not learned dominated convergence theorem

Comment: @DominicBlanco Oh Okay. I'll think of something else.

Answer (score 0):

As we discussed in a previous problem, write

$$\int_{0}^{n} (1 + \frac{x}{2n})^ne^{-x}dx= \int_{0}^{\infty}\chi_{(0,n)}(x) (1 + \frac{x}{2n})^ne^{-x}dx.$$

You're set up to use the MCT.

Comment: We are allowed to use dominated convergence now if you'd like to modify your answer.